# Ajax GET is failing hard

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi guys first time posting and total Ajax noob.

Just wondering if anyone can point out where I've gone terribly wrong, appreciate all the help i can get

//Jquery to handle ajax loading links

```
    //Function to handle back and forward

    var pooped = ('state' in window.history && window.history.state !== null),
        initialURL = location.href;

    //function to handle the scenarios where back and forward buttons used in browser
    $(window).bind("popstate", function (e) {
        // Ignore inital popstate that some browsers fire on page load
        var initialPoop = !pooped && location.href == initialURL;
        pooped = true;
        if (initialPoop) {
            return;
        }
        ajaxLinkPage(location.href);
    });

    // Ajax Link function
    var ajaxLinkPage = function (linkurl) {
        console.log(linkurl);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: linkurl,
            data: {},
            complete: function (data) {
            $('#body_wrap').html($("#body_wrap", data.responseText).html());
            history.pushState({
            page: linkurl
            }, linkurl, linkurl);
            }
            });
    };     

    // Below this is the Ajax Trigger
        $("#nav ul li a").click(function(){
          var linkurl = $("#nav ul li a").attr("href");
          ajaxLinkPage(linkurl);
         $('#dvLoading').css('display','block');
        });
```

- The ajax call doesn't work if i put event.preventDefault for the .click()
- Works in chrome on some pages but doesn't work at all in safari.

Thanks!

Comment: im pooped just reading this

Comment: Just add a return false; to your click event.

Comment: +1 for making me laugh

Answer (score 0):

Are you preventing default like this? It should work like so. If not can you post console errors if any?

```
$("#nav ul li a").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var linkurl = $("#nav ul li a").attr("href");
      ajaxLinkPage(linkurl);
     $('#dvLoading').css('display','block');
    });
```